# the version of the Java binary used (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java) is outdated

Tags: java, android, flutter

running flutter doctor gives:
flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.1, on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 6.5.0-25-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
    ✗ android-studio-dir = /home/devraj/Android/Sdk
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.87.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

when i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` it gives:

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/sdkmanager/SdkManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run
(/home/devraj/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code 1".
It appears the version of the Java binary used (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java) is
too out-of-date and is incompatible with the Android sdkmanager tool.
If the Java binary came bundled with Android Studio, consider updating your installation of Android
studio. Alternatively, you can uninstall the Android SDK command-line tools and install an earlier
version.
```

I have tried with default-java and java-22 as well same error occured

Comment: The error indicates you need Java 17.

Comment: Check your JAVA_HOME env variable, it probably still points to the Java 11. The Android SDK manager has been compiled with the JDK 17 (61). Make sure you have a JDK with higher version installed on your system and set the JAVA_HOME properly.

Comment: I have set the java home already